# Compilation error: invalid use of void expression

Tags: c++

I have a function which will pop task-codes from a queue and search it in a map of task-codes and tasks(methods) and push the the matched task into another queue which I want to pop out and executed sequentially later. Below is the function:

```
void CertManMgmtEECertController::PrepareTask()
{
    while(_taskCodeQueue.empty())
    {
        _taskQueue.push((_taskStore.find(_taskCodeQueue.pop()))->second);
    }
}
```

Below is the header where the class of this function is defined:

```
class CertManMgmtEECertController : public virtual CertManMgmtCertificate
{
    public:
        CertManMgmtEECertController();
        ~CertManMgmtEECertController();
        void PerformTask();
        void SetTask(CertManMgmtEETaskCode taskCode);
        typedef void (CertManMgmtEECertController::*Task)();

    private:
        CertManMgmtEETaskCode _task;
        queue<Task> _taskQueue;
        queue<CertManMgmtEETaskCode> _taskCodeQueue;
        map<CertManMgmtEETaskCode,Task> _taskStore;

        void LoadTasks();
        void PrepareTask();
        void ExecuteTaskQueue();
        void GetEECert();
        bool GetCertificate();
};
```

But I am getting this below error while compiling:

```
CertManMgmtDomainController.h:49: error: 'CertManMgmtEECertController' does not name a type
CertManMgmtEECertController.cpp: In member function 'void certman::CertManMgmtEECertController::PrepareTask()':
CertManMgmtEECertController.cpp:42: error: invalid use of void expression
CertManMgmtEECertController.cpp: In member function 'void certman::CertManMgmtEECertController::ExecuteTaskQueue()':
CertManMgmtEECertController.cpp:55: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Where am I going wrong? I know there are other compilation errors here too. Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then we can better help you locate the problem.  As your question currently stands, it is difficult to help without guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle the question contains enough information to answer about `invalid use of void expression` error.

[std::queue::pop()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) returns `void`. What you want in `PrepareTask` is probably

```
while (!_taskCodeQueue.empty()) {
//    ^^^ also fixed condition
    _taskQueue.push((_taskStore.find(_taskCodeQueue.front()))->second);
    _taskCodeQueue.pop();
}
```

Comment: __taskQueue_ is a queue of pointer-to-member functions. I am trying to call the function pointers:

`void CertManMgmtEECertController::ExecuteTaskQueue()
{
    Task fp = NULL;
    while(_taskQueue.empty())
    {
        fp = _taskQueue.front();
        (this->*fp)();
        _taskQueue.pop();
    }
    fp = NULL;
}`

But I am getting a seg-fault for this. I wanted to ask, is this the right way to call a function stored as a function pointer in a queue ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to ***start with the first error message***.

In your case that is

> ```
> CertManMgmtDomainController.h:49: error: 'CertManMgmtEECertController' does not name a type
> ```

Possibly you have a typo, possibly the header is not included in the implementation file, possibly the identifier has been redefined as a function, whatever. But start with this. Ignore the rest of the errors: they are <del>quite probably</del> possibly *caused* by this first one.

*Edit:* After writing the above I see in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31099816/464581) that you're using a `std::queue`, and indeed, its `pop` method returns `void`. This is for exception safety. There is [no convenience method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) that combines `pop` and `front`.

---

Regarding the typo possibility, note that

- modern IDEs such as Visual Studio provide tooltips about identifiers, and
- C++ provides *namespaces* to deal with common prefixes in a more practical way.

Answer (score 0):

See if adding `namespace` in `typedef` help.

```
 typedef void (certman::CertManMgmtEECertController::*Task)();
```